# Custom Subcategory Page on WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, customization, categories

I am working on a shopping cart WordPress site and I would like to customize the subcategory page. [Here is a link to my shopping cart](http://test.nextgennow.com/shop/).

When you click on that link you see only the product category images. Originally, you saw both the image and title, but that's not how I wanted it to be so I edited the `content-product_cat.php` file.

When you click on the Product Category it takes you to all the products that pertain to that category and is displayed the same way the product categories are - just the image. However, I want it to only display the titles, no images, just the titles. I understand that it's just showing the images because it's also using the `content-product_cat.php` file.

How can I make it so that only the product category shows images but the actual products show just the titles?

[Here is an example of what I want my site to do.](http://www.precisionroller.com/category/toner-cartridges.htm)

I am new to building eCommerce and WordPress sites so the more specific you are, the better.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi - this question is going to get downvoted or closed.  BUT, check out the template system - it's pretty powerful: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Comment: Thank you for your input! Why would this question get downvoted or closed?